Loading different OpenGL backend libraries under the same name
I am trying to build a fallback mechanism for OpenGL drivers in an application that uses GLFW and GLAD, where if the system provided library does not support 4.5 version, a Mesa implementation is used instead.
Let the system OpenGL library be opengl32.dll and Mesa one be named opengl32_mesa.dll.
I believe GLFW loads in the OpenGL driver libraries by the standard system name opengl32.dll. I could interject by using LoadLibrary* functions to select the correct implementation but the library names are different. If, I load opengl32_mesa.dll, then it won't be picked up by GLFW since it does not match the name it expects, i.e. opengl32.dll.
So, is it possible to load a library under a different name to facilitate this?

I'm not sure if this is easily possible. You'd have to load ALL functions (especially the wgl methods for creating the context) also as function pointers at runtime from the correct library. I'm quite sure that glfw doesn't support this, so you would have to write your own windowing layer.. But then the question arises how you know which OpenGL version is supported without loading the system OpenGL dll?

The other option would be to use dll injection mechanics (which should work with glfw), but you'd have to decide again before your program the dlls which version you want to use, which makes it hard to determine to supported GL version.

The general idea behind this question is troublesome, because it attempts to bypass windows' GL ICD mechanism completely, but winapi is not desgined to do that. For example, SwapBuffers is not a GL function, but a GDI one, which will call back into the ICD. However, you can work around that by directly calling Mesa's wglSwapBuffers instead, but it will always be a hack and is never guaranteed to work.
